# post array data from a row in table into another table php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql, submit, html-table

Ok so I am trying to accomplish an edit page and I cannot find anywhere that this has been posted previously.  I am using an array to pull data from sql and its coming in fine.  I want to specifically pull data from a single row to either edit it on one page or delete it on another depending on the button selected.  If I can get help on how to accomplish this please let me know.  I am utilizing php.

First Page

```
<?php
            include "cxn.php";
            $cxn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passwd, $dbname) or die ("CXN FAILED");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY userName";
            $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die ("query failed");
            $counter=0;
            echo "<table width=500px text-align=left>";
            echo "<tr><th style='background-color='black;'></th><th>User Name</th><th>Password</th></tr>\n";
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $fuserName = $row["userName"];
                $fpassword = $row["password"];
                echo "<tr><td style='width='50px';background-color='black';'>
                     <form method='post' action='edit.php' input='".$row."'>
                     <input type='submit' method='post' value='Edit'></form>
                     <form method='post' action='delete.php' input='".$row."'>
                     <input type='submit' method='post' value='Delete'></form>
                     </td><td style='width=200px;'>".$fuserName."</td><td style='width=200px;'>".$fpassword."</td></tr>\n";
                $counter++;
            }
            echo "</table>";
            ?>
```

Second Page

```
<?php
            include "cxn.php";
            $cxn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passwd, $dbname) or die ("CXN FAILED");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY userName";
            $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die ("query failed");

            echo "<table width='500px' text-align='left'";
            echo "<tr><th style='background-color='black;'></th><th>User Name</th><th>Password</th></tr><tr><td>\n";
            foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) 
            {
                echo "".$field." = ".$value." <br />\n";
            }
            echo "</td></tr></table>";
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first page `input=` is not a valid `<form>` tag attribute.
`<form method='post' action='edit.php' input='".$row."'>`

Comment: I marked as complete.  That was one of the problems.  The rest I was able to configure on my own and simplify what I was trying to accomplish.  Thanks!